# Set up parse server for parse livequery

Tags: parse-server

Does anyone have any introductory level walkthrough on how to set up a parse live-query? Do I just grab the latest version on [github](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) and it should have everything pre-set? I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many answers out there regarding the same question. However, i am just gonna give a brief how-to here.

Firstly, you can use download the parse server from [this github](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example).

In the index.js, if you read through it you should find something like

```
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
```

the classnames "Posts" and "Comments" are basically your database table names. I believe you are using mongoDB for your database right?

After which, once you upload the parse server to AWS/heroku, you should be ready to use live query.

On the client side, you just need to subscribe to table names you did at your server side and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks, very useful info!

Comment: where  index.js located?

Comment: Just saw your question @Arsenius, it should be directly in the parse server example.